# Why isn't $\sqrt[i\pi]{-1} = e$?

Tags: complex-numbers

My reasoning is through Euler's identity

$$e^{i\pi} = -1$$
$$\sqrt[i\pi]{e^{i\pi}} = \sqrt[i\pi]{-1}$$
$$e = \sqrt[i\pi]{-1}$$

but Wolfram Alpha [says otherwise](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?x=0&y=0&i=(i*pi)%20root%20of%20(-1)),  $\sqrt[i\pi]{-1} = -\pi$

So the way I see it, there are three options:

- Wolfram Alpha is wrong
- $-\pi = e$
- I am wrong

I'm pretty sure it's the latter. But why?

Comment: I think that this operation is not well defined.

Comment: You munged up the input.  Try [this instead](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?x=0&y=0&i=(-1)%5E(1%2F(i*pi))).  Though, as has been pointed out, there is not a *unique* answer---you have to make a choice of branch of log.

Comment: Maple  returns  $e.$

Comment: One should not *image* an operation for complex numbers by naively extending what is correct for the reals or integers. One would get less confused by forcing oneself to look at the **definition** of the concerned operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- "Wolfram Alpha is wrong"

It is.  It read this as $i\pi * \sqrt {-1} = i\pi * i = - \pi$.

Typing in $(-1)^{\frac 1{i\pi}}$ (I wasn't sure how to type in $n-th$ roots) [Wolfram Alpha gave $e$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?x=0&y=0&i=(-1)%5E(1%2F(i*pi))).

- "$-\pi = e$"

It doesn't.  But you should be careful about multiple values.  One can make a similar mistake that

$e^{2\pi i} = 1$ so

$\sqrt[2\pi i]{e^{2\pi i}}= \sqrt[2\pi i]{1} = \sqrt[2\pi i]{1^{2\pi i}}$

$e = 1$.

Which is obviously false.

But in actuality, $e^{k*2\pi i}$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$ so $\sqrt[2\pi i]{e^{k*2\pi i}}= \sqrt[2\pi i]{1}$ *actually* means $1 \in  \{e^k; k \in \mathbb Z\}$.  Which it is.  $1 = e^0$.

In your case $e$ is not the only possible value for $\sqrt[\pi i]{e^{\pi i}} = \sqrt[\pi i]{e^{\pi i+ 2k\pi i}}$ but $e^{1 + 2k}$ will be too.

- I am wrong.

Well,... not really.  But you have to watch out for multivalues and realize the answers you get will be congruence and not exact single values.  So when you *do* get something like $-\pi  = e$ one should wonder if there is some congruence between $-\pi$ and $e$.  But there isn't in this case.

===

Actually the entire concept of the $n$-th root $\sqrt[n]{}$ is a concept that doesn't really work well with complex numbers and is best avoided all together.

If one needs the "$z$th root" of something.  i.e. $w^z = v;$ solve for $w$. one should solve $z \ln w = \ln v$ bearing in mind that $\ln v$ is multivalued congruences modulo $2\pi i$.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the input field of the wolframalpha link, you would see that wolframalpha interpreted it as $(i\pi)\sqrt{-1}$.

And as to $\sqrt[i\pi]{-1}$, we are trying to solve $x^{i\pi}=-1$, i.e. $i\pi\ln x = i\pi+2ni\pi$, i.e. $\ln x = 2n+1$, i.e. $x=e^{2n+1}$, so any number of the form $e^{2n+1}$ is an $i\pi$-th root of $-1$.